# How to avoid user from changing radio button state?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a radio button which I have styled

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RadioButton" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>        
    </UserControl.Resources>

<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource  RadioButton}" Content="Server configured" Margin="10,10,10,10" IsChecked="{Binding serverStatus, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

It works nicely but the thing is that its only for display the user should not be able to change it.   If I set it to `IsEnabled="False"` I loose my formatting and cant see that the radio button was selected or not.  I also tried with using a checkbox it didn't help it just gets grayed out of you I disable it.

I suppose I could just use an image to display it but styling a radio button seams more elegant.

Question:  How do you style a disabled radio button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `Focusable="False"` and `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on your `RadioButton`. Then user will not be able to interact with it.

```
<RadioButton Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Style="{StaticResource  RadioButton}" Content="Server configured" Margin="10,10,10,10" IsChecked="{Binding serverStatus, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Comment: You sir are awesome! thank you so much that's exactly what I was after so simple.